# Firebase - Reset Password, check for previously used password

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

We are using the firebase's native support for resetting passwords. Now, we have a requirement of preventing use of previously used passwords and for that we are planning to store the hashed password in our DB, but the question is how do we intercept the firebase reset password function, can cloud functions be used in any way for this?

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Authentication doesn't support a feature like this. There is no way to intercept a password reset unless you build your own implementation, which I recommend. Only bonuses for it, you get your own unique design + you have full control of error checking and rules.

If you want to know how you create your own password reset landing page, check out the docs or this question: [Firebase - Customize reset password landing page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37932983/firebase-customize-reset-password-landing-page)